# Placing java components on gridbaglayout above and side by side in same layout

Tags: java, jtextfield, gridbaglayout, jslider

I have an array of JSliders and JTextfields and I want to place a JTextfield then a JSlider below, move left and place the next JTextfield, Jslider again.

```
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        JTextField[] textField = new JTextField[NUM_CHANNELS + 1];

        JSlider[] sliders = makeSliders(NUM_CHANNELS + 1);

        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CHANNELS + 1; i++) {

            textField[i] = new JTextField();

            textField[i].setText("Channel " + (i + 1));

            add(textField[i]);

            add(sliders[i]);
        }
```

With the above, I get JTextField - JSlider ... in a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add GridBagConstraints when you add your components

```
   GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
   for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CHANNELS + 1; i++) {
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        textField[i] = new JTextField();

        textField[i].setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));

        textField[i].setText("Channel " + (i + 1));

        add(textField[i], gbc);
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        add(sliders[i], gbc);
        gbc.gridx++;
    }
```